# Calculating partial derivatives of function

Tags: java, matlab, math, partial, derivative

I need to compute the first derivative of user-specified function. Program reads function as string from a file and then needs to compute derivative by one variable. Function has more variables, and can be linear or nonlinear.
What is the easiest way to do this?

Can calling MATLAB (maybe) be possible or whatever?

Program doesn't have any Internet accesses.

Comment: Is your problem, starting an UI implementation?

Comment: If I understand you, I can read that function as string, but don't know how to compute partial derivative by one of function's variables.  I red something about Apache but couldn't understand what is all about...

Comment: How are the powers given, with `^`?

Comment: "Nonlinear" is quite unspecific. If it involves anything else than the standard analytical functions, that will probably make the solution much less accessible.

Comment: The 'hardest' function that can be specified:
(sin(a1)*sin(a2)*sin(a3)*sin(a4))/(sin(a1+a5)*sin(a2+a6)*sin(a3+a7)*sin(a4+a8)), (nonlinear)
and the easiest is a5+a6+a7+a8. (linear)
It is functional model of some network Least Square Smoothing...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there is a Java library that can do this (or at least take the derivative) already.  You could probably call Matlab through JNI at worse (would essentially use the OS to call it), dunno if Matlab can be called directly.  Do you need to worry about simplification?  If you have to write this yourself, you need to parse it into a syntax tree, essentially.

Comment: When you say "calculating" - do you mean giving numerical answers, or do you mean doing symbolic differentiation?  If it's the latter, then you'll need to think more carefully about what can be included?  Should it deal with chained functions like sin(x^2 + 1)? Logarithms?  Fractional exponents?  I suggest you make a feature list, turn it into a list of tests, and make them pass, one by one.

Comment: Clockwork-Muse: I didnt found any library. @David: I need to determin their numeric value for creating design matrix for least square method, but must do this for every variable in function. In this function, nonlinear, i have only sin, and maybe somethimes cos, nothing else. It can be sin(one or more vars) , with possible constants included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a symbolic algebra library such as [javacalculus](http://code.google.com/p/javacalculus/).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javacalculus.core.CALC;
import javacalculus.core.CalcParser;
import javacalculus.evaluator.CalcSUB;
import javacalculus.struct.CalcDouble;
import javacalculus.struct.CalcObject;
import javacalculus.struct.CalcSymbol;

public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter expression:");
        String expression = in.nextLine();
        // javacalculus uses uppercase function names
        expression = expression.replace("sin", "SIN");
        expression = expression.replace("cos", "COS");

        System.out.println("Differentiate with respect to:");
        String variable = in.nextLine();

        // differentiate
        String command = "DIFF(" + expression + ", " + variable + ")";
        CalcParser parser = new CalcParser();
        CalcObject parsed = parser.parse(command);
        CalcObject result = parsed.evaluate();

        // compute numerical value
        result = subst(result, "a1", 0.0);
        result = subst(result, "a2", 10.0);
        result = CALC.SYM_EVAL(result);

        System.out.println("Result:");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static CalcObject subst(CalcObject input, String var, double number)
    {
        CalcSymbol symbol = new CalcSymbol(var);
        CalcDouble value = new CalcDouble(number);
        return CalcSUB.numericSubstitute(input, symbol, value);
    }
}
```

Sample input and output:

> Enter expression:
>   `sin(a1) * 4 * a2 + (a1 + 1)^2`
>   Differentiate with respect to:
>   `a1`
>   Result:
>   `42`

Comment: Thank you a lot :) It works, for now :)
But, this is symbolic solving. Do you know how can I now replace the vars with values I have already stored in array and get numeric value of derivative?

Comment: @Aleksandar  You are welcome. I updated my answer to compute the numerical value.

Comment: Thanks, again :)
I was one step to give up tih project by thinking differenting is not possible in Java :)

Comment: In general, you would use automatic resp. algorithmic differentiation for this task, as is done by the parser above for "DIFF(expr, a1)", hopefully building a parse tree and extending it for the derivative operations. See (http://autodiff.org) for libraries, tools and papers in various programming environments.

Comment: @LutzL I need your help again. Please, do you know how to write function with sqrt? I need it and program doesn't work. I am in hurry.

Comment: It does not have a specialized sqrt function, so you have to replace sqrt(x) with POWER(x,0.5). There is a DEFINE functionality, perhaps you can define a user function SQRT with this contents.

Comment: In general, this is a one-shot project that was born and died in 2009. No useful documentation available. Additionally, Java3D has long been abandoned, so one pillar of that project is broken. Their goal to re-implement Mathematica in Java (see todo list) was just too big.

Answer (score 0):

People, I would be very grateful if you tell me this thing more :)
I have function (same as above) and need to calculate it with same those values.
But I cann't pare it as `CalcObject` and then substitute and evaluate it.

```
    CalcObject result = parsed.evaluate();

    // compute numerical value
    result = subst(result, "a1", 0.0);
    result = subst(result, "a2", 10.0);
    result = CALC.SYM_EVAL(result);
```

and from subst(..)

```
    CalcSymbol symbol = new CalcSymbol(var);
    CalcDouble value = new CalcDouble(number);
    return CalcSUB.numericSubstitute(input, symbol, value);
```

Here I need to pass `CalcObeject` to `subst(...)` and then I can evaluate function. But how to do that? From string to `CalcObject`.

And is there some another solution or function for my problem?

**EDIT**

I needed to evaluate function from previous posts. My question was, how to do that and can I use Tom's method to do this. I have function, variables, and their values. Dont need to differentiate function, just to evaluate it.

*RESOLVED*

Maybe not the best way but it works. I made function a `(a1+a2+a3)*q` from `a1+a2+a3` and then I differentiate it by `q`. Now, my derivative if needed function which I can now evaluate using tom's way. :)

Thank anyway.
P.S. If some has better way, I'm here.

Comment: Please reformulate, your question here is not clear. To get a CalcObject from a string you must use the parser class CalcParser. Either on the expression `expression` or on the extended expression `command` that computes the derivative.

Comment: @LutzL Reformulated (maybe...) :)

Comment: Then use the CalcParser directly on the expression "(a1+a2+a3)" , without adding additional variables or DIFF directives.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit late, but.

If I'd like to inform you about MathParseKit.
https://github.com/B3rn475/MathParseKit

It is a C++ library that can be used to parse and solve functions.

Among all the functionality allow you to derivate a function by a variable.